# В чем разница между joinWith() и with() в Yii?

Tags: php, yii

При связи таблиц в запросе (Query) `joinWith()` или `with()`. В чем разница?

Comment: Когда `joinWith([])` в конструкцию SQL запроса добавляется LEFT JOIN таким образом одним запросом получит все связанные данные из бд. Когда `joinWith()` выполняется дополнительный запрос после основного - это полезно, когда надо жадный запрос, например получить все аватары для загруженных пользователей `select img from avatar where user_id in(1,2,3,4,5...n)`

Answer (score 0):

В чём разница - описано в [документации](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#joinWith()-detail)

> ### joinWith() public method
>
> **Joins with the specified relations.**
>
> This method allows you to reuse existing relation definitions to perform JOIN queries. Based on the definition of the specified relation(s), the method will append one or multiple JOIN statements to the current query.
>
> If the $eagerLoading parameter is true, the method will also perform eager loading for the specified relations, which is equivalent to calling with() using the specified relations.
>
> Note that because a JOIN query will be performed, you are responsible to disambiguate column names.
>
> This method differs from with() in that it will build up and execute a JOIN SQL statement for the primary table. And when $eagerLoading is true, it will call with() in addition with the specified relations.